# How can I verify the SHA256 hash of 0.10.3 "Wolfram Warptangent" on Ubuntu?

Tags: cryptography, linux, ubuntu, hash-verification

How can I verify the SHA256 [hash published](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt) for the official 0.10.3 release matches the file that I downloaded for Linux, 64-bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the correct download on the official [Monero website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) and go to your downloads folder. Open the terminal and use this command:

```
sha256sum monero-linux-x64-v0.10.3.0.tar.bz2
```

If you receive the following output you will know that the hash matches the [GPG signed message](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt) listing the correct SHA256 sums

> f164112bea75dfd3eaaa905d21129820a996bbe6e5d65cb194609c672a71c3fe  monero-linux-x64-v0.10.3.0.tar.bz2

Answer (score 2):

Jun Li's answer is correct. You can also use the '-c' (for check) option to sha256sum to verify the hash without manually comparing hash strings, but you have to extract the hash line from the *hashes.txt* file first, because of [this bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26263).

The steps are:

1. Download the *monero-linux-x64-v0.10.3.0.tar.bz2* and *hashes.txt* files
2. Copy the relevant line from hashes.txt to a separate file. For example use this command in the terminal: `grep linux-x64 hashes.txt > linux-hash.txt`
3. Run the check command in the same folder as the *.bz2* file: `sha256sum -c linux-hash.txt` . This should print 'OK' if the download is not corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

The hashes.txt file seems to be badly formatted and has 2 spaces between the filename and the hash, making the sha256sum command look for the wrong file (it's prepended with a space). If everything is downloaded into same folder, you can do:

`sed 's/  / /g' hashes.txt | sha256sum -c`

The `sed` command fixes the double spaces "on-the-fly".

The output will look something like:

```
$ sed 's/  / /g' hashes.txt | sha256sum -c
sha256sum: monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.1.zip: No such file or directory
monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.1.zip: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-win-x86-v0.10.3.1.zip: No such file or directory
monero-win-x86-v0.10.3.1.zip: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-mac-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-mac-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
monero-linux-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: OK
sha256sum: monero-linux-x86-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-linux-x86-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-linux-armv8-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-linux-armv8-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-linux-armv7-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-linux-armv7-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-freebsd-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-freebsd-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-dragonflybsd-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-dragonflybsd-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
monero-gui-win-x64-v0.10.3.1.zip: OK
sha256sum: monero-gui-mac-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-gui-mac-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: monero-gui-linux-x86-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
monero-gui-linux-x86-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: WARNING: 22 lines are improperly formatted
sha256sum: WARNING: 11 listed files could not be read
```