# Downloaded monero v12 GUI How do I verify the hash of the download on Ubuntu command line?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, hash-verification

I downloaded the latest monero v12 client using the following command:

```
curl -O -J -L  https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/linux64
```

I never knew how to go about verifying its hash. How do I go about verifying this downloaded file is the same hash as shown on the site using the command line? Do i untar it first or do i leave it as tar file and do the verification?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I verify the SHA256 hash of 0.10.3 "Wolfram Warptangent" on Ubuntu?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/how-can-i-verify-the-sha256-hash-of-0-10-3-wolfram-warptangent-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it against the downloaded file.

I used the command:

```
sha256sum <my_file_here>
```

It will then spit out a hash string. Copy this string and then do a find on that same webpage to see if it matches.

It was pretty easy. Took less than 30 seconds to figure out.